# Is there an Azure cli for these AWS cli sentences?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I'm used to AWS and aws cli (`aws-shell`), so if want to upload the content of a folder called `images` to a certain bucket, I used to type this in the `aws-shell`:

```
s3 cp ./images/ s3://mybucket.com/images/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.jpg" --acl public-read --storage-class STANDARD --content-type "image/jpeg"
```

I have to migrate to Azure blobs and I don't know how to do that. More over, what would be the equivalent to aws-shell to do that? azure-cli?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload a folder in Azure Blob Storage, the AZ CLI command you would want to use is [`az storage blob upload-batch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch).

Other option would be to use [`azcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) tool which is designed specifically for performing various blob operations. You can find examples of uploading files and folders using azcopy here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json

> More over, what would be the equivalent to aws-shell to do that?
> azure-cli?

That's correct. Other option would be to use [`Azure PowerShell Cmdlets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/what-is-azure-powershell?view=azps-8.3.0).